# Pass Array and Assign in C++ Class

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am a Python dev and very new to C++ and trying to wrap my head around arrays and pointers etc. I am trying to pass an array to a class, have that class assign the array to a class variable/member and have an accessor and mutator for said array.

```
class ArrayClass {
public:
    // Constructor
    ArrayClass(int array[]) {
        classArray = array;
    };

    // Accessor
    int getArray() {
        return classArray;
    };

    // Mutator
    void setArray(int newArray) {
        classArray = newArray;
    };
private:
    int classArray[];
    };

int main() {
    int createArray [] = {1, 2, 3};
    ArrayClass newObject(createArray);
};
```

I have tried some different combinations but can't seem to get on the right path. Should a pointer be used here?

I am used to being able to just either pass in a list in Python or even declare the list I am passing right in the argument and then being able to assign that parameter to any variable inside the class.

Any help here would be appreciated!

Comment: There is `std::array<>` that is the `c++` array that you can pass by value and return from a function. The `c` array you use does not pass by value or return.

Comment: C++ is not Python.  Do not use Python (or frankly any other language) as a model when writing C++ code.  For example `int classArray[];` is not valid C++.  No C++ book would have a declaration like this.

Comment: `#include <array>  int main() {std::array<int, 3> createArray = {1,2,3}; auto newObject = createArray;}` -- That is basically everything your code attempted to do.

Comment: I missed in my comment that you also can't do this: `classArray = array;` Assignment does not work with a `c` array.

Comment: I would use `std::vector<int>` or `std::array<int, N>`. The low level arrays that you are using are really for advanced, low level work. Then your task should be as easy as in Python.

Answer (score 0):

For any newcomers to C++ like me, the answers by Galik and drescherjm were perfect. I switched to using

`std::array<int, 3>;`

and it worked the way I was expecting, with pass by value.